# Visual Studio 2010 "System.Web" reference unresolved [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

I'm having trouble with adding a reference to my project. I need the `System.Web` reference in order for my code to work but the reference won't stick. When I look in the Solution Explorer, I found this alert icon on top of the reference I added. I have the same reference in another project within the same solution and it is working fine.

[image: The reference that has an alert icon on it]

If you look at the properties of this reference, you'll see that the `Resolved` attribute is set to `False`

[image: The properties of this reference]

Does anyone know how I can fix this or what's causing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing it, recompile, adding again? Have you closed your solution? Clean solution might also help

Comment: What is the target framework of your project (right on the project -> applicaton tab) ? System.Web is not supported in client profile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good chance that your project is targetting **.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile**. System.Web is not supported by the client profile. Change it to **.NET Framework 4.0**.

Comment: This answer is already provided as a comment. Let him get the glory ;)

Comment: Then they should have posted it as the answer than as a comment.

Comment: Special thanks to namesv for coming up with the solution first. Thanks as well to Maarten for your response.